# How to map using multiple variables in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, functional-programming, mapping

I need help with this,

I have a list of lists and a list of dictionaries. The list of dictionaries has for its values, list of indexes that point to the items in the list of lists.
what I need to do is to create a new list of dictionaries from those other two.

```
list_1 = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f], ...]

list_2 = [{key_11: [0,2] , key_12: [0]}, {key_21: [2,0], key_22: [1]}, ...]
```

The values of the **first** dictionary in list_2, point only to the **first** list o list_1 and so on...

What I need is a new list of dictionaries with the same keys but with values of the items on list_1[i] represented by the values of the dicts on list_2.
So something like this:

```
return [{{key_11: [a,c] , key_12: [a]}, {key_21: [f,d], key_22: [e]}, ...]
```

I tried something like this:

```
return [{key: some_funct(val) for key, val in x.items()} for x in list_2]
```

and some_funct takes a value of the dictionary and returns the correct items on list_1[x] for x in list_2

I know I'm close! but I can't get some_funct to work properly and I think it's because I'm trying to map three things, every element on list_1, every dictionary on list_2 and every value for each dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `zip` here to iterate through both lists concurrently. Then for every such list, we use *dictionary comprehension* to map the elements in the list to their counterparts.

Like:

```
[{k:[sub1[v] for v in vs] for k, vs in sub2.items()}
 for sub1, sub2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

this produces - with your sample input:

```
>>> list_1 = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']]
>>> list_2 = [{'key_11': [0,2] , 'key_12': [0]}, {'key_21': [2,0], 'key_22': [1]}]
>>> [{k:[sub1[v] for v in vs] for k, vs in sub2.items()}
...  for sub1, sub2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
[{'key_12': ['a'], 'key_11': ['a', 'c']}, {'key_21': ['f', 'd'], 'key_22': ['e']}]
```

How does it work?

The outer part is *list comprehension*. We iterate over `zip(list_1, list_2)` so we obtain the rows of `list_1` and `list_2` so to speak. These rows `sub1` and `sub2` are a list and a dictionary respectively.

For every such `sub1, sub2`, we construct a dictionary in the resulting list. This dictionary is constructed with *dictionary comprehension* `{k:[sub1[v] for v in vs] for k, vs in sub2.items()}`. We iterate through the key-value tuples in the `sub2` (the `sub2.items()` and for every such key-value pair we associate the key `k`, with a value that is constructed through list comprehension again, based on the value of the dictionary `vs`.

`vs` is thus a list associated with the key in the dictionary, all we have to do is obtain the element that is associated with the index, so we perform a mapping `[sub1[v] for v in vs]`.